# Connecting an app in ArgoCD to use a Helm OCI repository

Tags: amazon-ecr, argocd

I can see the Argo seems to support OCI repositories but I can't seem to get this to work.

First I can only seem to add repositories through the CLI because there is no option for enabling OCI.
`argocd repo add <uri> --type helm --name name --enable-oci`

However, when adding an app using the UI the argo server is logging "unsupported protocol scheme ''" when selecting the repository. I have tried a URI with HTTPS and empty (as mentioned in the issues).

Is it possible to use the UI for OCI repositories or is it a command line thing only?

I am using Argo version 2.0.4

Answer (score 1):

I used the following command and it worked for me.

```
argocd repo add <acr name>.azurecr.io --type helm --name <some name> --enable-oci --username <username> --password <password>.
```

You can also try to configure it declartively: [issue-7121](https://github.com/argoproj/argo-cd/issues/7121)

```
apiVersion: v1
stringData:
  enableOCI: "true"
  name: my-oci-charts
  password: token-password
  type: helm
  url: registry.gitlab.com/asdasd/charts
  username: token-name
kind: Secret
metadata:
  labels:
    argocd.argoproj.io/secret-type: repository
  name: my-oci-charts
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I may have confused the sentence about the oci. I could enable oci repositories from cli but not the GUI. After adding the repo from the oci I could not add apps through the UI using the repo added by the cli

Answer (score 1):

Looking like they've added it to UI in argo v2.7.0-rc1 based on their feature list.  Still need to try it when I get a chance.

04db457: feat(helm): set enableOCI in the UI when registering a repo (#12420) (@alexef)