# ArgoCd - Failed to connect Helm repository

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, artifactory, argocd

I have the following ecosystem:

- K8S version: v1.24.9
- ArgoCd version :  v2.6.7+5bcd846
- gitlab
- Private helm repo (Artifactory)
- Helm version : 3.10.3

I am trying to deploy an application présent on the gitlab repo. The application contains links to my private Helm repository (Artifactory).

I successfully configured the gitlab repos and the helm repo in the "repository" section.

Argocd fails to add Helm private repo when I go through creating an application.
Here is the error message in the argocd (repo server & server) cd logs (debug mode):

```
level=error msg="finished unary call with code Unknown" error="`helm repo add --username ****** --password ****** --ca-file /app/config/tls/xxx.xxxx.xx helm-virtual https://xxxx/helm-virtual/` failed exit status 1: Error: looks like \"https://xxxxx//helm-virtual/\" is not a valid chart repository or cannot be reached: Get \"https://xxxx/helm-virtual/index.yaml\": tls: server chose an unconfigured cipher suite" grpc.code=Unknown grpc.method=GenerateManifest grpc.service=repository.RepoServerService grpc.start_time="2023-05-20T19:03:51Z" grpc.time_ms=695.406 span.kind=server system=grpc
```

```
tls: server chose an unconfigured cipher suite
```

the call is between which component?

I tested the call manually from the argocd-repo-server and from the argocd-server and it works. I debug mode does not give more logs.

I also added on argocd the certificate of my private registry as well as the CA.

do you have any idea ?

Thank for your help.

Comment: Check if your Helm repository is an OCI one and if that's the case see for example here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68219458/connecting-an-app-in-argocd-to-use-a-helm-oci-repository

Comment: unfortunately, it doesn't work. I have the same error.